# Is there a way of approximating a percentage decrease with the natural logarithm?

Tags: logarithms, percentages

my question stems from this nice approximation of a percentage *increase*: for small percentage increases (usually below 20%), we can have an approximation with the natural log of the ratio. Here's an example:

50 increases to 55 --> % increase is (55-50)/50 (usually multiplied by 100, but let's keep it decimal for the time being)

OR

we could approximate it and say it is ln(55/50) or ln(55)-ln(50).

My question, then, is: is there a way to approximate a percentage *decrease* as well?

Think of it as a discount: the price was 55 and now it's 50. The discount is 1 - 50/55, or (55-50)/55. However, I really can't find a log approximation that simulates what the other one does and has the two following properties:

1. The values of the percentage decrease and the approximation are similar for small percentage decreases.

   2. As the decrease gets larger (say, for instance, from 1000 to 50), the function (I'm assuming it'll be a log) keeps smoothing the decrease in a **monotonic** way (so from a linear enlargement of the decrease, we get a marginally diminishing one, just as it happens for the increase in the initial example).

Any ideas?

---

One thought I had was that, in general terms, you can positively express an increase as $(b-a)/a$ and a decrease as $(b-a)/b,$ so to get from the second to the first you can multiply the second by a/b. So you can find something decent with $\ln(b/a)*a/b$. If you do that, however, you end up with something like: 
$$
    \begin{array}{lll}
    ~       &    \text{% Decrease} &    \text{Log decrease} \\
       50   &    0.0909      &    0.086645618  \\
    60      &    0.1667      &    0.151934631  \\
       100  &    0.5000      &    0.34657359   \\
       500  &    0.9000      &    0.230258509  \\
       1000 &    0.9500      &    0.149786614  \\
    \end{array}
$$

Comment: As far as I am aware, the natural log function already does exactly what you are asking for. Could you give some more specific examples showing a percentage decrease, how you applied the natural log in each case, what the result of the natural log was, and what kind of result you expected?

Comment: One thought I had was that, in general terms, you can positively express an increase as (b-a)/a and a decrease as (b-a)/b, so to get from the second to the first you can multiply the second by a/b. So you can find something decent with ln(b/a)*a/b. If you do that, however, you end up with something like:

Comment: http://truben.no/table/#t=XQAAQABpDwAAAAAAAAA9iIhmlCK88bNBnMeko9jCKiwvfJt7hC80L1hchidRiCzauW3NNf29umyoaNSFRAUnG6p53KbetHHYrjnL98IccknXIyj_I8tKLyinrdVQlnzkTUyilC3VQYNJVA6Fp5legWv3T5zuCYvrC2k_YJX44-_kZTiDD8Sa1JpiKwrWRRxrVvXQMk-oD9dgFJzeD7nfMcuFt7sOpiP9ph8l3gBX7CEkKDTrhGCHRgvnc-mQgHQE4QsIVv30YryLjNjgBPJAFHfGGAzMsM4ALqD2VlTKgcOR6IKpH1k_EgkNoST9xhVuJPKkCbWsQT2hbo_dOwq1xa4ZcM53Hw8IpD4z0qYCBc8jz-xeGkmavKzK_tel2WDoSWnmdc_yFYjzqDLYDdn6ftPq6FBxO4Qshgw99cTPHpGJuipN93LF7Af8ndGq

Comment: So after a certain point, it stops being monotonic and the decrease doesn't get larger. I'm looking for something that stays monotonic.

Comment: Use the "edit" button at the bottom of the question text to edit new information into the question. Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation if you're having trouble formatting a table.

Comment: I don't think "monotonic" or "smooth" are the correct words for what you're trying to say.

Comment: Monotonically increasing then, maybe smooth isn't. Anyway, I edited it with a link that shows a nicely formatted table.

Comment: The "edit" button at the bottom of the question text is meant for you to use to add information such as your table. I've done it for you this time since the formatting is not the most obvious (you have to do it within a math environment, not an ordinary LaTeX environment).

Comment: Now that I've put together what you wrote, I see an inconsistency in your formulas. The formula for percent change from $a$ to $b$ is $(b-a)/a.$ If you like you can call this the formula of the percent increase, and the formula of the percent decrease is $(a-b)/a$ (because an n% decrease is just a -n% increase). If you now want a single formula that gives a positive number for every change, you could try $|b-a|/a$; but this is ambiguous (you get a number, but is it an increase or decrease?), and the absolute value function is not monotonic.

Comment: Thank you, David. I'm not looking for a single formula that gives a positive number for every change. What I'm looking for is, a bit counter-intuitively (but this is the purpose I need it for), is a function (probably some combination of natural logarithms) that gives me an approximation of a percentage decrease as a positive number for small changes, an approximation of a percentage increase as a negative number for small changes, and, as the change gets larger, the imprecision of the approximation is such that the actual change is bigger than the log change (this is the smoothing effect).

Comment: The thing that I like about applying logarithms to percent change is that it restores a symmetry that the "percent change" tends to obscure. For example, to undo a 20% decrease, you need a 25% increase; to undo a 95% decrease, you need a 1900% increase. But a log decrease of magnitude 0.6 (ln(b/a) = -0.6) can be undone by a log increase of 0.6. A log decrease of magnitude 3.0 (approx. 95.02% decrease) is reversed by a log increase of 3.0 (approx 1908.6%). If you don't want this symmetry, maybe logarithms are not useful for you.